# multiple videos on html5 canvas?

Tags: video, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm making this media project and I'm running into a big problem. I essentially wanted a 4x4 grid of 16 videos, but I'm getting lag issues of course. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this with canvas. Can I composite multiple videos, will that speed it up as opposed to having 16 separate video elements?
If you click on this link:
http://graysonearle.com/bluemen/
And hit PLAY ALL (then TEST, later) on the left side, you can see what I mean. It actually works most of the time, but sometimes not. I'm also going to add longer videos.
Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Very late answer but here goes:

You can of course render multiple video elements on one canvas element with JS. Videos are basically treated as images so you could render the video for each RAF frame.

```
ctx.drawImage(YourVidID, 0, 0, 100, 100);
ctx.drawImage(YourVidID2, 100, 100, 200, 200);
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there some requirement keeping you from just creating one video that's an aggregate of all 16 videos instead of rendering them individually?